# SQL count a specific item

Tags: sql-server, mysql

say, I had a table as follows:

| weekending | NextEvent |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-06-15 | :2018-06-15 |
| 2018-06-22 | 2018-06-29 |
| 2018-06-29 | 2018-06-29 |
| 2018-10-12 | 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-10-19 | 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-10-26 | 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-11-02 | 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-11-09 | 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-11-16 | 2018-11-16 |

and I want to count such that it looks like this:

| weekending | NextEvent | Weeks until |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-15 | :2018-06-15 | 0 |
| 2018-06-22 | 2018-06-29 | 1 |
| 2018-06-29 | 2018-06-29 | 0 |
| 2018-10-12 | 2018-11-16 | 6 |
| 2018-10-19 | 2018-11-16 | 5 |
| 2018-10-26 | 2018-11-16 | 4 |
| 2018-11-02 | 2018-11-16 | 3 |
| 2018-11-09 | 2018-11-16 | 2 |
| 2018-11-16 | 2018-11-16 | 1 |

I'm basically counting down the weeks until the next event day. Is there a way i can use the aggregate count function to achieve this? I know it can probably be done with doing some count over row numbers, but i'm looking to avoid it. Thanks guys

EDIT: also, my date data doesn't follow the calendar exactly. It's certain days for certain things. So Date Diff wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Is there a problem using DATEDIFF(week, weekending, nextevent) ?

Comment: Yeah, my date data has certain rules imposed on it. I'll edit to update

Comment: Use a service like https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV- to provide sample data that illustrated the problem. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with certain rules

Comment: I think that I understand what you expect as output, but your sentences and edit under the example confuse me. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Given the example set in your post, it's not very clear how `DATEDIFF` would fail there.  Also, there's an inconsistency with your example, or at the very least it's not very intuitive. The first two events go `(0)`, `(1, 0)`. And the last one goes `(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`.  Why doesn't it end with a `0` like the other two? In other words, why not `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)`? Could you please expand your data sample with cases illustrating your point about `DATEDIFF` being inapplicable? That would also help us see what the output should look like in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to count how many `weekendendings` have same `NextEvent`. One way to do this with T-SQL in SQL-SERVER is with `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT
      weekending
    , NextEvent
    , ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY NextEvent ORDER BY weekending DESC) AS [Weeks until]
FROM yourtable
```

Here is [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/szjZFjJx)

This is similar like [example in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-simple-examples). Only difference here is that you work with dates.

Comment: Perhaps the order should be by `weekending DESC`, so that the numbers are assigned in the reverse order. Also, if the last item is expected to be 0, you'd probably also need to subtract 1 from the result.

Comment: @AndriyM I agree with `weekending DESC`, I wrote that in fiddle example, but forgot to update answer, thank you. I noticed that in some cases [Weeks until] is 0, but for 2018-11-16 last item is 1, so I wasn't sure.